# Google Execution API calling Google-Apps-Script = Error 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I have a Power Shell script importing data into Google Spreadsheet. Works just as expected: set up the Project Credentials, Scope, Token refresh...
After the data is imported I need to call a Google Apps Script that belongs to the Spreadsheet. I've followed the steps from:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api
(deployed, same project, enabled API, same user...)

Unfortunately, PS Script says (403 = Forbidden):

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At S:\projekte\controlling\ctlac.ps1:163 char:12
+ ...   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $acc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

This is the line of code giving the error:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $request |ConvertTo-Json With $request being: { "function": "fnTest" }
```

what am I missing? Is it supposed to work at all?

TIA

Comment: Usually 403 errors are permissions related.  Do you know that your authentication method is working?

Comment: I want to believe it's working because all other Spreadsheet operations are working. Unfortunately, not API Explorer for Google Execution API so I'm having a tough time trying to debug this. Any other way of finding out WHY it's forbidden?

Comment: unfortunately no.  We'd be able to explore it more if we owned the servers, but since it is a cloud solution we have to go with the information we're given.  Could you edit your question to post the full line of code that is throwing the error?  (Line 163 of ctlac.ps1)

Comment: $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $request |ConvertTo-Json

With $request being:
    {
        "function":  "fnTest"
    }

Comment: In your google apps script, is it published publicly, or do you need to authorize the account you've set up the token for to be able to call it?

Comment: I went to "Deploy as API executable", "Who has access to the script" = "anyone". .

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the same docs you've provided, make sure you have met the [requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api):

> 1. The Apps Script project containing the function must be deployed as an API executable.
> 2. he calling application must supply the API a valid OAuth token. This OAuth token must cover all the scopes used by the script (not
>      just the ones used by the called function).
> 3. The script and the calling application must share the same Cloud Platform project.

Deducing from your 403 error, you're having trouble with #2 which is related to access token. Make sure you're OAuth authorized.